# add a new relation between existing records in FileMaker Pro 19

Tags: filemaker

I have two tables with data and am looking for a function to add a relation between them.

Table A holds people (site managers) and table B holds sites. A site-manager can be responsible for several sites, but a site only ever has one manager. Table B has a "ref_manager" reference field that points to table A's UUID field.

Adding a new relation on the site layout is easy as I can simply make a selection field populated from the site-manager table.

But adding a new relation on the manager layout eludes me despite searching and experimenting. I do have a portal with a list of currently assigned sites and I can delete them there. But I want to add as well - either within the portal or outside of it.

I do **not** want to create new records, only to add new relations between records, in this case by setting the reference field in table B.

What am I missing? This is a common use case and should be simple, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an existing site to the current manager using a script that:

1. Stores the current. manager's ID in a variable;
2. Shows a list of all (or some) sites in a new window (e.g. a card window);
3. Upon user selecting a site, sets the selected site's ManagerID field to the variable;
4. Closes the window (and possibly refreshes the original window or its portal).

You can use some other method to select the site to add - but the point is that the action needs to be performed on the selected site record - which is currently NOT related to the active record.

Sometimes it can be convenient to add another relationship that shows all sites (or all unrelated sites) in a 2nd portal - and have the user select the site from there. In such case your script can operate directly on the record in the selected portal row, without leaving the current layout.

Comment: So there is no way to show a dropdown menu with a list of all sites, pick one from there and have a button "add this site" next to it?

Comment: Sure there is. You can use a global field for this. Then either find the selected site or use a relationship to another TO of Sites to make the selected record related so you can modify it's foreign key field directly.